# Firebase realtime database retrieve data into list and use it on barchart

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, charts

So I'm creating a pedometer app and I'm using Firebase realtime database to save my users daily steps count.
And I'm trying to create a `Barchart` which would show my user his whole weeks daily step count.

Here's my database

[image: Database]

And here is my code so far.

```java
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private BarChart barChart;
    private int steps;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    DatabaseReference fDatabase;
    private Context mActivity;
    private String paiva;
    private boolean showSteps = true;
    private List list;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container,false);
        barChart = (BarChart) v.findViewById(R.id.bargraph);
        pref = mActivity.getSharedPreferences("com.kuntoappi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        fDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String data = ds.getValue().toString();
                    list.add(data);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

So I get my database `dayId` and steps into my list but problem is my code puts both `dayId` and steps into same index when I need them separate in my `Barchart`.

I'm very lost how to retrieve data properly from Firebase and I've read like million different docs but I still can't get it.
If anyone can help with my problem I would be thankful.

**EDIT**

So here is my barchart method which should create barchart using my database data and update it accordingly when database receive new data. Ive tried different things but i cant get my head around how i can insert my data into this barchart.
Somehow i should format my string values to float and insert them to my barchart.

Im using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

I want my barchart look something like this

[image: Bar Chart]

```
private void createBarChart() {

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return Days.get( value);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate the `dayId` & `steps` data for you to work with, you can do something like:

```java
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        String dayId = ds.getKey(); // Friday, Saturday, etc.
        String steps = ds.child("Steps").getValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This solved one of my problems, but now i just need to figure out how do i apply these on my bar chart. You got any suggestions on how to create simple chart which shows values on different weekdays?

Comment: Can you share your current code related to your chart setup? Without any existing code it's hard to give concrete pointers/help.

Comment: I added my barchart code. It aint much but im still trying to figuring it out.